# Rename multiple files with bash for loop, mv, and sed

Tags: bash, sed, rename

My goal is to rename a folder of files of the form 'img_MM-DD-YY_XX.jpg' to the form 'newyears_YYYY-MM-DD_XXX.jpg' by iterating through each filename and using sed to perform substitutions based on character positions. Unfortunately I cannot seem to get the position-based swaps to work.

e.g. `s/.\{4\}[0-9][0-9]/.\{10\}[0-9][0-9]/` attempts to replace MM with YY

Here is my attempt (neglecting for now the _XX part):

```
for filename in images/*
do
newname=$(echo $filename | sed 's/.\{4\}[0-9][0-9]/.\{10\}[0-9][0-9]/;
            s/.\{7\}[0-9][0-9]/.\{4\}[0-9][0-9]/;
            s/.\{10\}[0-9][0-9]/.\{7\}[0-9][0-9]/;
            s/img_/newyears_20/')
mv $filename $newname
done
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: You might have better luck using `awk` instead of `sed`.

Comment: You should use zsh - `zmv 'img_(??)-(??)-(??)_(??).jpg' 'newyears_20$3-$2-$1_0$4.jpg'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ echo 'img_11-22-14_XX.jpg' | sed -r 's/[^_]*_([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/newyears_20\3-\1-\2/'
newyears_2014-11-22_XX.jpg
```

The above looks for anything up to and including the first underline followed by a 6-digit date.  It replaces the initial part with `newyears_` and reformats the date from mm-dd-yy to 20yy-mm-dd.

The two-digit mm, dd, or yy values are matched with `([0-9]{2})`.  The parentheses indicate that `sed` should capture the value for later use.  The output side of the substitution is `_20\3-\1-\2`.  This restores the underline and adds a `20` to the front of the year.  The year was the third captured value so it is denoted `\3`.  Likewise, the month was the first captured value so it is denoted `\1` and the day the second so it is `\2`.

To eliminate some blackslashes, I used the `-r` option to invoke extended regular expressions.  If you are on a Mac or other non-GNU system, use `sed -E` in place of `sed -r`.  Otherwise, use:

```
sed  's/[^_]*_\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/newyears_20\3-\1-\2/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to do with `awk`

```
echo "img_MM-DD-YY_XX.jpg"  | awk -F"[_-]" '{print "newyears_20"$4"-"$2"-"$3"_0"$5}'
newyears_20YY-MM-DD_0XX.jpg
```